# dynamic css active class on ul li reflect according to url changes using angualar js

Tags: angularjs

dynamic css class active applied on li while clickin on li and each li contain link.but if we open a link then dynamic css class  active not working properly.
so how can i develop that type of functionality like after book mark perticular li link then when we open that link its need to be selected.

html

```
  <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down' : item.selected, 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right' : !item.selected}" style="display: block;line-height:20px;">
            <span ng-click="showChilds($index)">{{item.name}}</span>
            <ul>
                <li ng-click="showGlyph(subItem);" class="sub-item" id="sub-item-{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-envelope' : subItem.active}" ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems" ng-show="item.selected">
 <a ui-sref="{{subItem.url}}">
                    <span>{{subItem.name}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

javacript controller

```
 $scope.showGlyph = function(subItem) {
            angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
                angular.forEach(item.subItems, function (sItem) {
                    sItem.active = false;
                });
            });
            subItem.active = true;
        };

        $scope.showChilds = function(index){

            $scope.items[index].selected= !$scope.items[index].selected;
            collapseAnother(index);

        };
        var collapseAnother = function(index){
            for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
                if(i!=index){
                    $scope.items[i].selected = false;
                }
            }
        };
        $scope.items = [
            {
                name: "Item1",
                subItems: [
                    {name: "SubItem1" ,url:'user.create'},
                    {name: "SubItem2" ,url:'user.edit'}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Item2",
                subItems: [
                    {name: "SubItem3",url:'user.new'},
                    {name: "SubItem4",url:'user.old'},
                    {name: "SubItem5" , url:'user.newnew'}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Item3",
                subItems: [
                    {name: "SubItem6" , url:'user.oldold'}
                ]
            }
        ];
```